# Eliminating White Space in WordPress Themes

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do I raise the contents closer to the head? The Left column should be closer to the dancing baby.   The main area (starts with About Us) should be closer to the menu Fun Fun Fun.    Don't worry about the white space above the menu... I have plans for that area.   AND... can the answer help with other WordPress themes?  ie;  is there some CSS coding to do?

http://fun.mrchuckw.com

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do for long-term learning and development of WordPress themes is to learn how to use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx).

Like this: [image]

Those tools will allow you to see what's loading on your site and in the theme and let you work with and change the CSS and HTML and see the results before you make changes to the style sheet and templates of the theme.

And, make a child theme of your MetroX theme so any changes you make will stay if you update the parent theme. See [Child Themes « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Answer (score 0):

I read through the page's source code, you want to open your theme's CSS page, [this](http://fun.mrchuckw.com/wp-content/themes/metro-pirate/style.css?ver=4.2.2) link here. Under the **"==========Header========="** section, you should reduce the values of (or completely remove) the **padding/margin-top**.